# Panel events won't work in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi all
I'm struggling with some problem in a project from college.
I'm building a "4 in a row" game in c# for a project in my c# course at my college.

I have created a Form named GameForm and inside it I added a Panel named panelBoardGame.
to that panelBoardGame I added an array of labels to be clickable (to execute a move) and i added a matrix of labels too , to represent the Board itself.

Now, my mission is whenever the mouse is inside the Panel area, the CoinImage of a certain player is moving along with the Cursor as long it is inside the panel area. when the mouse is outside the area, the CoinImage wont show.

To do so I tried triggering the onMouseEnter,OnMouseLeave events of the panelBoardGame, but somehow they wont even get executed. 
Whenever my mouse is inside the panelBoardGame area the code inside panelBoardGame_MouseMove(......) function doesn't get executed.

Anyone could help me with that?

Since im new here i cant post images, but ive uploaded the image to here **[Image of the Form](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/81/formwithapanelinsideit.jpg)**

Here is the image of the Form, inside it with a border in black around it is the panel and inside the panel i added labels

Comment: ive added an image of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me guess, your labels completely cover the the area of the panel.  In Windows only the top control receives mouse events.  So when the mouse is over one of your labels the mouse events go to the label, not to the panel that contains the label.  So set a MouseMove event handler on your labels and you'll see that execute.

Comment: Yes, the labels covers all the area in the panel. I want whenever my cursor moves in the panel area, to have an image of a Coin following it and when the Cursor moves out of the panel, i want the Coin to disappear

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the Move and Hover events go to the topmost control (the labels). Is any of your Panel showing?

You might be able to Capture the mouse in the MouseEnter event of the Panel.

```
boardPanel.Capture = true;
```

But this might interfere with the mouse-handling in the labels.

All in all, you'll probably find that getting this (UI) right is a lot harder than it looks. Consider a simpler act-on-click design. To start with.

Comment: The Form events do get executed, but the panel events won't. For example. GameForm_OnMouseEnter/Move Works but panelBoardGame_OnMouseEnter/Move doesn't get executed